# In WSO2 IS 5.9.0 how to configure Password Policies And Login Policies with help of an API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to find the REST/SOAP API for Password Policies (Password History and Password Pattern) and Login Policies (Account Locking and Account Disabling).

I am using WSO2 IS 5.9.0.

I am creating a Multi-tenant environment from WSO2. I am able to perform all the steps from code but not able to find API for these two settings.

I have to manually do this but this is just a workaround and need to figure out the WSO2 APIs for these.

[image]

[image]

Need curl request or documentation for these 2 settings API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WSO2 IS 5.10.0 onwards there is a rest API to update these configurations.

However, in 5.9.0 and before that, only SOAP APIs are available. You can use https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityGovernanceAdminService SOAP service for this purpose. There are 2 operations available in this service. `getConnectorList` and `updateConfigurations`.

You can use `getConnectorList` to find the available connectors and their property names. Then you can use `updateConfigurations` operation to update property value. Message body would look like below to update `Password History validation count` configuration.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gov="http://governance.identity.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gov:updateConfigurations>
         <gov:configurations>
            <xsd:name>passwordHistory.count</xsd:name>
            <xsd:value>6</xsd:value>
         </gov:configurations>
      </gov:updateConfigurations>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help .....can you please send the curl request for the request or just the request url for both the requests?